Has defer attribute made JS non parser blocking?
I understand that both CSS and JS block DOM construction from this answer. However, since the defer attribute allows downloading script in background. Hasn't it made JS resources loaded with <script defer src="..."> render-blocking rather than parser blocking?
script loading with defer and async attributes
I read this article 
